# Wrapping Qt libraries

Tags: discussion, questions

I understand that recommendation questions are hate-magnets. I don't believe that the question I'm *trying* to ask violates the guidelines, but I haven't been able to ask in a way that doesn't getting down-voted into oblivion ([SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31257177), [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/288950)). Specifically, I'm trying to find out what features two tools/packages have for a particular use-case, or if there's another tool out there somewhere that I haven't found yet.

The particular case is wrapping Qt libraries in a way that allows me to build a RESTful server, among a whole bunch of other implementations. The two tools/platforms that I'm aware of are Swig and Thrift. I've read the blog articles, looked over the tickets, done the homework, read the manuals, installed the demos, etc. I'd love to know, from someone with experience actually doing this, whether either or both of these has features that make wrapping Qt libraries straight-forward. I'm not asking for people's preferences or recommendations. I'm looking for something like:

- There's a Qt plugin on github that lets you add a CONFIG = swig in your .pro file. Here's a link.

or

- Thrift tried to support Qt 4, but it was too hard and the project was abandoned.

or

- Qt does this all by itself, using the following 20 lines in your .pro file...

or even

- Here's a link to another project that you might not have heard of that does this...

(all of which I'm making up). How do I ask the question without attracting the ire of the community because the question sounds like I'm asking for a recommendation? Or is this really something that I can't ask on StackOverflow?

Comment: So you want to ask a question that isn't a product recommendation in which people recommend products for you to use?

Comment: Not at all. The question could be asked like:
- How do I integrate Swig into a Qt project? Here's what I've tried...
- How do I use Thrift for a Qt library? Here's what I've tried...
- How do I call a Qt library from an Apache module/PHP source/...? Here's what I've tried.

Comment: *"or if there's another tool out there somewhere that I haven't found yet."* definitely should omit that from the question. pushes it into the area of "off-site software recommendation." If someone has such a recommendation, they'll likely add it without you asking for it anyway.

Comment: No matter how you word *"Is either objectively technically superior to the other for this particular usage"* it's still going to bring about opinionated answers unless you specify what would make one or the other "superior". For example, asking to compare between two methods based on which is fastest would be on topic (but, you'll need to provide more information to limit the testing down to a specific environment), but based on which is "best" would not.

Answer (score 4):

It will only fly if you pick Swig and start wrapping your REST server with it.

When you run into an issue ask a question about that. In your question you can state that you know Trift but are not sure if that doesn't have the same problem.

Answers to your question will either solve your issue in Swig or suggest to switch to Trift.

An other option might be to check if there is a chatroom that has Qt as its topic.